# Properties of Galois group on splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ and let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be the its pairwise different roots in its splitting field $L_f$. Let
$$\Delta = \prod_{i<j}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j) \quad \quad and \quad \quad \Delta^2 = \prod_{i<j}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2$$

There are 3 tasks: 
a) Show that for any $\sigma \in Gal(f)$: $\sigma(\Delta)=\Delta \iff \sigma$ is even and $\sigma(\Delta)=-\Delta \iff \sigma $ is odd 
b) Show that $\Delta^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ 
c) Show that $\Delta \in \mathbb{Q} \iff Gal(f) \leq A_n$

My thoughts: 
a) I would intuitively say that since an element of the Galois group maps zeros to zeros (of $f$) then when the indices $i$ and $j$ get "swapped" exactly $k$ times, where $k$ is the amount of transpositions that represent $\sigma$. I don't know how to formalise this.
b) I would say that $\Delta^2$ is invariant under any element of $Gal(f)$ and hence an element of $\mathbb{Q}$ 
c) This should follow from $a)$ since any element of $A_n$ can be written as product of an even number of transpositions.

I would like to see a mathematical formalisation of $a)$ and complaints in case my thoughts in b) and c) are wrong

Comment: Isn‘t $\sigma(\Delta)=\Delta\iff\sigma(-\Delta)=-\Delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts on b) and c) seem to be right, in each case the element is in $\mathbb Q$ because it is invariant under the operation of the Gaois group on it:

For b) this is the case because $\sigma(\Delta^2) = \sigma(\Delta)^2$ and from a) we know that $\sigma(\Delta)$ either $\Delta$ or $-\Delta$.

For c) this is the case because as you rightly asserted each element $\sigma \in A_n$ can be written as the product of an even number of transpositions, so $\sigma$ is even so by a) $\sigma(\Delta) = \Delta$, this is an equivalence by a).

For a) (I assume you meant $\sigma(\Delta) = -\Delta \iff \sigma$ is odd) we take a look at how the sign is defined, as a permutation is even/odd iff its sign is even/odd:

$$sign(\sigma)=\prod_{i<j}\frac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}$$

So we get:
$$\sigma(\Delta)=\prod_{i<j}(a_{\sigma(i)}-a_{\sigma(j)})=\prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)\frac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{i-j} =\prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)\cdot\prod_{i<j}\frac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}=sign(\sigma)\prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)$$ $$ = sign(\sigma)\Delta$$

Where the second equivalence is due to the fact that if $\sigma(i)<\sigma(j)$ we get the factor $a_i-a_j$ in $\Delta$ and $\sigma(\Delta)$ and if $\sigma(j)<\sigma(i)$ we get $a_j-a_i = -(a_i-a_j)$ in $\sigma(\Delta)$. This clearly shows both equivalences.